# Docker pool space allocation issue

Tags: docker

customer has configured 8TB as the physical volume (/dev/sdc) and created logical volume group (vg_sys) with 8TB. As per the installation guide (cloud deployment guide for Azure), they created the logical volumes as shown in the lvs output as shown below. The remaining space (around 7 TB) got allocated to docker-pool during the installation time.

```
[root@vm-bp-uaa-prod-1-new /]# lvs

  LV          VG     Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert

  homelv      rootvg -wi-ao----  11.00g                                                    

  optlv       rootvg -wi-ao----   4.00g                                                    

  rootlv      rootvg -wi-ao----  17.00g                                                    

  tmplv       rootvg -wi-ao----  12.00g                                                    

  usrlv       rootvg -wi-ao----  10.00g                                                    

  varlv       rootvg -wi-ao----   8.00g                                                    

  docker-pool vg_sys twi-aot---  <6.94t             1.13   0.62                            

  optabc    vg_sys -wi-ao---- 900.00g                                                    

  var         vg_sys -wi-ao---- 100.00g
```

Recently, we have had some problems about the size of the directories (opt/abc)and when are full, the software presents a lot of problems.

1. It appears, docker-pool used all the available free volume group space after doing the partitioning while executing pre requisite for the installation ? Why it is happening ? Is there any parameter or config where we can limit the use of available VG free space allocated to thin docker pool LV ?
2. We wanted to confirm the procedure if it is possible to reduce some space from docker-pool logical volume and assign it to some other LV (optabc). We tried with “lvresize” and “lvreduce” but these command were failing with this message. (Thin pool volumes vg_sys/docker-pool_tdata cannot be reduced in size yet.)

I have attached the output of the following commands taken from customer prod environment in the file - disk partition.rtf

```
df -kh

pvs

vgs

lvs

lsblk

pvdisplay

vgdisplay

lvdisplay
```

docker info

I have attached the output of the following commands taken from customer prod environment in the file - disk partition.rtf

```
df -kh
pvs
vgs
lvs
lsblk
pvdisplay
vgdisplay
lvdisplay
docker info
```

Comment: You can't attach RTF files on Stack Overflow.